# Central Limit Theorem, Skewed Distribution and outlier detection

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, inference, descriptive-statistics, outliers

I'm trying to see how the CLT can help when trying to detect outliers in a distribution. Say I'm pricing houses in a location and that the resulting distribution of my sample of prices is rightly skewed. Now, let's assume there are some very low and high prices that were clearly measurement errors of some kind and I want to remove them.

Is the following line of thinking correct? And does the CLT help in any way to the objective of outlier detection in this setting:

*First, using t- or z- scores to say, "I'm going to remove any value that is greater than 2/3/4 standard deviations from the sample mean" would be incorrect since the distribution in question is not normal. Doing so would likely result in the removal of very large outliers, but it would it be too strict in the left side of the distribution (i.e. it would remove values that are not small enough to reasonably be considered outliers).
Now, since the sample size of housing prices is n=100, I can invoke the CLT and assume the sampling distribution of the mean housing prices is almost normal. But.. is the CLT even relevant here?*

Comment: The CLT doesn't help here, I think, unless your concern really is with the sampling distribution of the mean in (much) larger samples. Your data are skewed and you are worried about outliers. These are different problems. (Quite separate issue is that a set of house prices isn't at all a plausible example here. Some very high house prices are exactly what I expect in most cases and I certainly wouldn't to remove them as outliers or talk about measurement error. Naturally, this is a picky comment and you could change the example.)

Comment: Thanks. You mention the CLT would help if my concern would be with the sampling distribution of the mean: could you state an example of when this would be the case? I have seen many cases where sample size of surveys  are large withe hopes to invoke the CLT. I'm curious to see how the CLT applies in these situations. On a side note: was my assumption in t- and z- score correct?

Comment: I am trying to hint tactfully that you seem confused here. It seems that you are confusing or conflating the distribution of the data and the distribution of the sample mean. There are many tests for outliers, so there is no need to try to think up your own; nevertheless you may have a hard job identifying that is really plausible.